# Transitioning Laravel App into WordPress (Portfolio Website)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm re-creating my website in WordPress since I can't afford to provide the financial upkeep for my Laravel Portfolio website.

In my Laravel application, I have an easy way of creating a new project (an object) and adding it to the database. Afterwards, I can create a page where all of the projects I've created is displayed.

Is there a similar way of doing this with WordPress? I am creating my own WordPress Theme so I can understand WordPress better.

Note: I've tried adding ACF to a page and then just adding all the information, but if I create a new project, it seems I have to duplicate a ACF of the page and then get the data by doing get_field() method which in my opinion is not what I should be doing.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I was looking into creating a Custom Post Type, but I'm not sure how to display them all in one page. Archives seems like a good place, but what if I don't want previous projects to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Post Type is always a preferable approach.
To display all the projects in custom page template you need to learn few concepts for WP.
1.custom page template (To display your custom content)
2. WP_Query ( Fetch custom post type data with lot of advance query).
For your reference please find the below documentation.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/